# Стоит ли использовать Glut для OpenGL вместо WGL для инициализации в Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, glut, c++, opengl

Больше всего пишу под `Windows`, и ее `WinAPI` меня начинает раздражать. Инициализирую окно с поддержкой `OpenGL` через `WGL` и `WINAPI`, но его громоздкость и неповоротливость(я так считаю) меня отталкивает и местами путает. Смотрю на код с инициализацией `OpenGL` на `GLUT` - там все красиво и понятно. Собственно вопрос: что я потеряю, а что приобрету поменяв `WINAPI` и `WGL` на `GLUT`?
P.S. Иногда встречались посты на форумах что-то типа "Для новичка `GLUT` - зло". Правда ли это?

Comment: Сделайте один раз иннициализацию окна на WinApi и после используйте реализацию во всех своих ПО, зачем каждый раз ее переписывать?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как смотреть. Библиотека GLUT - это своеобразный каркас, в некотором смысле прогибающий Вашу программу под себя. ИМХО, каркас этот весьма годится для всяких небольших программок, но неприменим для мало-мальски сложных приложений или игр. Однако, если предлагаемая событийная модель удобна - почему бы её не использовать?

Лично я выбираю WinAPI. Всё-таки этот вариант гораздо более гибок. И окошко можно создать какое угодно, и события ОС перехватываем, какие хочется(хотя, честно говоря, статические callback'овые методы что у GLUT, что у WinAPI, мне не нравятся - приходится извращаться чтобы уйти от них), и контекст OpenGL можно инициализировать любой версии, хоть OpenGL 4.0 (правда, там нужно сначала всё равно создать старый, получить через него функцию расширения и дёрнуть его).

По идее, GLUT скрывает за собой платформозависимый код, а собственно настройку OpenGL и рисование через него делает программист. Думаю, если Вы не будете лениться и заменять отрисовку своих моделек glutSolidTeapot =) , эта библиотека только позволит углубиться в изучении собственно графики, что есть самое настоящее добро даже для новичка.